# Is Sax parser suitable to parse xml files that can be up to 10 gb in size?

Tags: java, sax

I have a task to create a parser that will process xml files up to 10 gb in size (Yes I know its stupid to process such big files, but that's the way it is in this system). A colleague has said that Sax parser cannot handle that despite the oracle documentation saying that is more or less the purpose of it. Is it correct to say that sax parser cannot handle such large files because the server will crash despite it having 32 gb of ram? Is it necessary to create our own parser and not rely on what oracle says? [sax parser docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxp/sax/when.html)

Comment: Do not try to do this without SAX.  This is what SAX parsers are for.  If you can't find a sufficiently performant SAX parser, you're unlikely to be able to make one yourself.

Comment: [SAX](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxp/sax/index.html) parser can handle infinitely large XML files. Of course, if *your code* stores all the parsed data in memory, you'll still run out of memory, but that's not the parsers fault. --- On a side note, I'd suggest using [StAX](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxp/stax/index.html) parser instead, as they are easier to write, and can also handle infinitely large XML files.